# Unit test Hangfire with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, hangfire, nsubstitute

I am trying to unit test my class which includes a background job. So far my method which I am testing Enqueues a job and looks like this:

```
public void SendSms(SmsContent content){
      .... 
      _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<ISms>(x => x.Send(content));
      ....
}
```

My first unit test check if BackgroundJobClient is called and looks like this:

```
 Assert.Equal(1,_backgroundJobClient.ReceivedCalls().Count());
```

All works fine but now I want to check all the parameters if the are correctly sent. I was looking over the [HangFire documentation](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/v1.0.2/users-guide/background-methods/writing-unit-tests.html) but I couldn't figure that out how can be teste with NSubstitute.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
_backgroundJobClient.ReceivedWithAnyArgs()
                   .Enqueue<ISms>(x => x.Send(default));
```

Comment: This seems to work fine, however, I can't figure it out how to check the params sent to Send method.

Comment: I'm not sure. Test this code: `_backgroundJobClient.Received().Enqueue<ISms>(x => x.Send(content));`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [example in the docs](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/writing-unit-tests.html) you should be able to test it using something like this:

```
/* Moq example:
client.Verify(x => x.Create(
    It.Is<Job>(job => job.Method.Name == "CheckForSpam" && job.Arguments[0] == comment.Id.ToString()),
    It.IsAny<EnqueuedState>());
*/

// Ported to NSubstitute:
_backgroundJobClient.Received().Create(
    Arg.Is<Job>(job => job.Method.Name == "CheckForSpam" && job.Arguments[0] == comment.Id.ToString()),
    Arg.Any<EnqueuedState>()
);
```

This is only based on the documented example. The exact arg matching code you need will depend on the specific types you are using.